# Kinesis giving AccessDeniedException while creating KinesisProducer object

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-kinesis

While creating KinesisProducer object, I am getting this error:

---

"logger":"c.a.s.k.p.LogInputStreamReader","message":"[2023-06-22 14:53:30.647705] [0x00001b78] [error]
[shard_map.cc:152] Shard map update for stream "kinesislog" failed.
Code: AccessDeniedException Message: User: arn:aws:sts::<>:assumed-role/<>
is not authorized to perform: kinesis:DescribeStream on resource: arn:aws:kinesis:us-east-1:<>:stream/kinesislog
because no identity-based policy allows the kinesis:DescribeStream action; retrying in 30000 ms"}

---

I am able to put records to kinesis, in addition to that, I am not able to catch AccessDeniedException